# Convert DynamoDb stringset into JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, unmarshalling

This is one of the fields of **StringSet** type that is returned from DynamoDb.

```
permissions:
       Set {
         wrapperName: 'Set',
         values:
          [ 'BannerConfigReadOnly',
            'CampaignBannerCreate',
            'CampaignPromoCreate',
            'CampaignReadOnly',
            'MasterplanReadOnly',
            'SegmentCreate',
            'SegmentDownload',
            'SegmentUpload' ],
         type: 'String' } 
    }
```

Now, I am using **aws.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshal** function to get it in this format

```
permissions: ['BannerConfigReadOnly',
            'CampaignBannerCreate',
            'CampaignPromoCreate',
            'CampaignReadOnly',
            'MasterplanReadOnly',
            'SegmentCreate',
            'SegmentDownload',
            'SegmentUpload']
```

But, this is what i get

```
{}
```

Any ideas what, I may be doing wrong.

This is my code

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const documentClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
documentClient.scan(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      let processedItems = [...data.Items];
    var test = aws.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(processedItems[0].permissions);
      console.log(`test is ${JSON.stringify(test)}`);
    }});
```

ProcessedItems[0] is this

```
{ email: 'abc@gmail.com',
  tenant: 'Canada',
  permissions:
   Set {
     wrapperName: 'Set',
     values:
      [ 'BannerConfigReadOnly',
        'CampaignBannerCreate',
        'CampaignPromoCreate',
        'CampaignReadOnly',],
     type: 'String' } }
```

Comment: That data is already unmarshalled since you are using the `DocumentClient`. Consider just using `processedItems[0].permissions.values` to get the values of the set.

Comment: Thank you @cementblocks that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data is already unmarshalled since you are using the `DocumentClient`. Consider just using `processedItems[0].permissions.values` to get the values of the set.

Comment: I mixed up and didn't realize i had change my code to use DocumentClient that already unmarshalls the DynamoDB response. haha
Thank you for pointing that out.